# How do I set a different material in the viewport from the one used in the final render?

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I made a material consisting of a Fresnel-weighted mix between a Principled BSDF and a Translucency node. This material looks as intended in Cycles, but in the viewport it is excessively darkened. Ideally, I would like to have a separate version of this material, without the translucency, for use in the viewport, while still using the original in the final render. This would also be useful when working with the Principled Hair BSDF, which doesn't currently work in the viewport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another method is one object, two materials and use GN to set your material:

[image]

...which has the advantage of not increasing your polycount/memory usage.

Comment: Would the node setup be the same if I was applying it to a hair system?

Comment: "should" work i hope - but i never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 seperate objects.

- One object for the viewport with your viewport-only material.
- Another object for the render with your render-only material.

[image]